# Integrate Google Assistant to Facebook Messenger using Action Builder

Tags: dialogflow-es, integration, actionbuilder

In DialogFlow exists an option to integrate automatically to Messenger from Facebook. How can I do the same integration using Action Builder on Actions Console? Is it possible or a hybrid version is a better option to implement?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no integration in actionbuilder to integrate with any platforms other than Google Assistant. Action builder is [intended](https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/announcing-actions-builder-actions-sdk.html) to improve development for actions for Google Assistant by bringing the conversation design part of development into the Actions Console.

If you want to develop for Messenger you are better off sticking with Dialogflow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But can I do a hybrid version with intents and Messenger integration on DialogFlow and a Google Sign In part on Action Builder? Is it possible?

Comment: Google sign in in action builder / the actions console is intended for Google Assistant. If you want to use Google Sign in you should look at facebook's documentation to see if they can provide any integration.